# Why does my python 2.7 process use an incredbly high amount of memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I am trying to understand why this python code results in a process that requires 236 MB of memory, considering that the list is only 76 MB long.

```
import sys
import psutil

initial = psutil.virtual_memory().available / 1024 / 1024
available_memory = psutil.virtual_memory().available

vector_memory = sys.getsizeof([])
vector_position_memory = sys.getsizeof([1]) - vector_memory

positions = 10000000

print "vector with %d positions should use %d MB of memory " % (positions, (vector_memory + positions * vector_position_memory) / 1024 / 1024)
print "it used %d MB of memory " % (sys.getsizeof(range(0, positions)) / 1024 / 1024)

final = psutil.virtual_memory().available / 1024 / 1024

print "however, this process used in total %d MB" % (initial - final)
```

The output is:

```
vector with 10000000 positions should use 76 MB of memory 
it used 76 MB of memory 
however, this process used in total 236 MB
```

Adding x10 more positions (i.e. `positions = 100000000`) results in x10 more memory.

```
vector with 100000000 positions should use 762 MB of memory 
it used 762 MB of memory 
however, this process used in total 2330 MB
```

My ultimate goal is to suck as much memory as I can to create a very long list. To do this, I created this code to understand/predict how big my list could be based on available memory. To my surprise, python needs a ton of memory to manage my list, I guess.

Why does python use so much memory?! What is it doing with it? Any idea on how I can predict python's memory requirements to effectively create a list to use pretty much all the available memory while preventing the OS from doing swap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) function only includes the space used by the list itself.

But the list is effectively just an array of pointers to int objects, and you created 10000000 of those, and each one of those takes memory as well—typically 24 bytes.

The first few numbers (usually up to 255) are pre-created and cached by the interpreter, so they're effectively free, but the rest are not. So, you want to add something like this:

```
int_memory = sys.getsizeof(10000)

print "%d int objects should use another %d MB of memory " % (positions - 256, (positions - 256) * int_memory / 1024 / 1024)
```

And then the results will make more sense.

---

But notice that if you aren't creating a `range` with 10M unique ints, but instead, say, 10M random ints from 0-10000, or 10M copies of 0, that calculation will no longer be correct. So if want to handle those cases, you need to do something like stash the `id` of every object you've seen so far and skip any additional references to the same `id`.

The Python 2.x docs used to have a link to an old recursive `getsizeof` function that does that, and more… but that link went dead, so it was removed.

[The 3.x docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) have a link to [a newer one](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504), which may or may not work in Python 2.7. (I notice from a quick glance that it uses a `__future__` statement for `print`, and falls back from `reprlib.repr` to `repr`, so it probably does.)

---

If you're wondering why every `int` is 24 bytes long (in 64-bit CPython; it's different for different platforms and implementations, of course):

CPython represents every builtin type as a C struct that contains, at least, space for a refcount and a pointer to the type. Any actual value the object needs to represent is in addition to that.<sup>1</sup> So, the smallest non-singleton type is going to take 24 bytes per instance.

---

If you're wondering how you can avoid using up 24 bytes per integer, the answer is to use [NumPy's `ndarray`](http://www.numpy.org/)—or, if for some reason you can't, the stdlib's [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

Either one lets you specify a "native type", like `np.int32` for NumPy or `i` for `array.array`, and create an array that holds 100M of those native-type values directly. That will take exactly 4 bytes per value, plus a few dozen constant bytes of header overhead, which is a lot smaller than a `list`'s 8 bytes of pointer, plus a bit of slack at the end that scales with the length, plus an `int` object wrapping up each value.

Using `array.array`, you're sacrificing speed for space,<sup>2</sup> because every time you want to access one of those values, Python has to pull it out and "box" it as an `int` object.

Using NumPy, you're gaining *both* speed and space, because NumPy will let you perform vectorized operations over the whole array in a tightly-optimized C loop.

---

<sub>1. What about non-builtin types, that you create in Python with `class`? They have a pointer to a dict—which you can see from Python-land as `__dict__`—that holds all the attributes you add. So they're 24 bytes according to `getsizeof`, but of course you have to also add the size of that dict.</sub>

<sub>2. Unless you aren't. Preventing your system from going into swap hell is likely to speed things up a lot more than the boxing and unboxing slows things down. And, even if you aren't avoiding that massive cliff, you may *still* be avoiding smaller cliffs involving VM paging or cache locality.</sub>

Comment: sounds likely. But it raises another question, why an int object should use 24 bytes!?

Comment: @snoopy Every object in CPython has to include at least a refcount, and a pointer to its type. So, on a 64-bit platform, the smallest non-singleton objects are 24 bytes.

Comment: What a darn good answer! Thank you for all the knowledge you are transmitting!